# Has anyone had success installing evolution-ews on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, dependencies, evolution

I wanted to install `evolution-ews` on `Debian 10`. I have already installed evolution, which went error-free. When trying to install `evolution-ews`, I get the following error(s):

```
$ sudo apt install evolution-ews
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 evolution-ews : Depends: libecal-1.2-19 (>= 3.22.6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libedata-cal-1.2-28 (>= 3.22.6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libevolution (>= 3.22.6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libevolution (< 3.23) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: evolution (>= 3.22) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: evolution (< 3.23) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.22) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: evolution-data-server (< 3.23) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

- So just to test if I could install any of these dependencies, I was surprised to find that all of them are already installed.

```
$ sudo apt install libecal-1.2-19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libecal-1.2-19 is already the newest version (3.30.5-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt install libedata-cal-1.2-28
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libedata-cal-1.2-28 is already the newest version (3.22.7-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt install libevolution
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libevolution is already the newest version (3.30.5-1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt install evolution
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
evolution is already the newest version (3.30.5-1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt install evolution-data-server 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
evolution-data-server is already the newest version (3.30.5-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
$
```

As you can see, all the dependencies that the `evolution-ews` package requires, are already installed with their versions being either newer or at least up-to-date with what `evolution-ews` requires.

- Just for fun, I checked for any "broken" packages, as the original error message talked about "broken packages being held back".

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ^..r
$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E ^.[^nci]
$ dpkg --audit
$
```

As you can see, the output of all those commands is clean. No broken packages.

The output of `apt-mark showhold` indicates no held packages.

So that makes me wonder at this stage:  how could `evolution-ews` which it seems is a broken package make its way into the Debian repositories - Debian which is supposed to be the "stable distro". Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On debian Buster the `evolution-ews` package is only available on buster-backports.

Add buster-backports to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

then install [`evolution-ews`](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/evolution-ews) :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -t buster-backports evolution-ews
```